# How to capture change event to update controller/data, when using ui-router and "controller as" syntax?

Tags: angularjs

I'm sure for the enlightened this is a pretty basic question.

I'm using Angular 1.4.x, and ui-router (0.2.15), and Controller As syntax.

The app/page displays the dollar amounts for certain business areas, and has a couple dropdown boxes for filtering the data (the filters are sent in the web request to the service, and new data is retrieved from the server).

I have the first page load working, I get the data from the initial web service call, but I can't figure out how to capture the change event from the dropdown boxes and cause it to reload/refresh the controller/data.

(for clarity, I am using Chosen by Harvest for the dropdown boxes. "Chosen-Select". And I'm using ASP.Net MVC 5 for backend.)

This is my controller:

```
.controller('AppModulesController', function (UserAppModulesService, $scope, $state) {
var appModulesController = this;

appModulesController.GetData = function () {

    var csCostCenter = $("#costcenter.chosen-select").val();
    var csProvName = $("#providername.chosen-select").val();
    var csProvSpec = $("#providerspecialty.chosen-select").val();
    var csProvStatus = $("#providerstatus.chosen-select").val();
    var csProvSpecType = $("#providerspecialtytype.chosen-select").val();


    // Create a WebRequestObj
    var wro = new WebRequestObj(
        "noname",
        "Cube_MS12",
        [], // the ASP.Net MVC controller selects the Measures, so those will not need to be set here
        [], // this request requires no dimensions
        [new filterObj("[MS Dim Service Date].[Dtof Svc Year Month]", ["CURRENT"])]
    );


    // get the current value of the Chosen Select Filters, and add the values to the WebRequestObj
    if (csCostCenter !== null) { wro.filters.push(new filterObj("[MS Dim Cost Center].[Cost Center Name]", csCostCenter)); }
    if (csProvName !== null) { wro.filters.push(new filterObj("[MS Dim Provider].[Provider Name]", csProvName)); }
    if (csProvSpec !== null) { wro.filters.push(new filterObj("[MS Dim Provider].[Provider Specialty]", csProvSpec)); }
    if (csProvStatus !== null) { wro.filters.push(new filterObj("[MS Dim Provider].[Provider Status]", csProvStatus)); }
    if (csProvSpecType !== null) { wro.filters.push(new filterObj("[MS Dim Provider].[Provider Specialty Type]", csProvSpecType)); }


    //send request
    var json = JSON.stringify(wro);
    appModulesController.userAppModules = UserAppModulesService.query({ json: json });  //.$promise.then();
}


appModulesController.GetData();

});
```

The Partial / Template:

```
<div class="appModuleboxes" ng-repeat="userAppModule in appModulesController.userAppModules">
    <div class="appModuleboxName">
    <a ui-sref="subhome({id:userAppModule.Id})">{{userAppModule.Name}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="appModuleboxValue" id="ambv-{{userAppModule.Id}}">
    {{userAppModule.Value}}
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the index.html (.cshtml):

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="reporting">
    <div class="row" id="holdfilterrow">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div id="appslider">
                    <div ui-view="appmodulelist"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                            <div class="filterboxtext">Cost Center</div>
                            <select id="costcenter" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="ALL" multiple>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            @foreach (string costcenter in ViewBag.costcenters)
                            {
                                if (costcenter!= "")
                                {
                                    <option value="@costcenter">@costcenter</option>
                                }
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
            <<<<snip out rest of select boxes>>>>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <a ui-sref="home">Home Link</a>
</div>



</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/ngApp/Reporting/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/ngApp/Reporting/services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/ngApp/Reporting/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/ngApp/Reporting/controller.appmodule.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/ngApp/Reporting/controller.subhome.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/cubewebrequestobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/chosen.css" />

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".chosen-select").chosen({
                single_backstroke_delete: false,
                search_contains: true,
                no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
                width: "100%"
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

This is the app.js / state config:

```
angular.module('reporting', [
'ui.router',
'ngResource',

'reporting.services',
'reporting.controller'
])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            "appmodulelist": {
                templateUrl: '/ngApp/Reporting/partial-appmodule.html',
                controller: 'AppModulesController as appModulesController'
            },
            "report": {
                //templateUrl: '/ngApp/Reporting/partial-home.html',
                //controller: 'HomeController as homeController'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('subhome', {
        url: '/subhome/:id',
        templateUrl: '/ngApp/Reporting/partial-subhome.html',
        controller: 'SubHomeController as subHomeController'
    })

    .state('dog', {
        url: '/dog',
        views: {
            "appmodulelist@": {
                templateUrl: '/ngApp/Reporting/partial-dog.html'
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Again, to be clear, When I change a dropdown filter, how do I capture that change event and tell the controller to re-run/reload?

Thanks for your help.

========== EDIT ===========

I found a way to get it working, but it doesn't feel right. Since the event happens outside Angular, I handle the event outside via JQuery, and then call into the Angular controller:

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
            $(".chosen-select").on("change", function (evt, params) {
                angular.element('#appmodulecontroller').scope().appModulesController.GetData()
            });
        });
```

I don't really like this, but I'm guessing I'll need to restructure the page/code to do something more pure Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-change on your select to call a method in your controller.

Here is a small exemple

```
<select ng-change="TransactionCtrl.updateQtyInStock()"  ng-model="TransactionCtrl.currentTransaction.uom" repeat-on="TransactionCtrl.uomList" class="form-control input-lg" selectpicker="{ dropupAuto: false }" toggle-dropdown data-style="btn-white btn-lg">
    <option ng-repeat="uom in TransactionCtrl.uomList" ng-selected="uom.name == TransactionCtrl.currentTransaction.uom" value="{{uom.name}}">
         {{uom.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you. Is there an issue of scope, as the controller that I want to update is not the same one that created the dropdown (currently I create the dropdowns without angular). So, can I call  ng-change="TransactionCtrl.updateQtyInStock()"
when the element was not created by TransactionCtrl?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't create the dropdown in the controller? You could also use $rootscope that's probably not a best practice but it should work.

Comment: your input got me thinking, and I found a way to get it to work. I think I'll end up changing the filters to be handled by angular, or the numbers to not be. Marking this as the answer.